# Unity gradle build duplicate entry

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, gradle

I have been developing a game and on top of google play games services I added admob and facebook sdk. Up to the point of adding admob it everything was working but after adding facebook sdk I've reached the 64k dex limit. So I decided to use gradle. When building I got a few errors that I was able to solve, but I've stumbled upon this error:

```
CommandInvokationFailure: Gradle build failed. 
C:/Program Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_121\bin\java.exe -classpath "C:\Program Files\Unity\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\AndroidPlayer\Tools\gradle\lib\gradle-launcher-2.14.jar" org.gradle.launcher.GradleMain "assembleDebug"

stderr[

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':transformClassesWithJarMergingForDebug'.
> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: com/google/android/gms/ads/internal/overlay/zza.class

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
]
stdout[
Incremental java compilation is an incubating feature.
:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
:preDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
:checkDebugManifest
:preReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
:GoogleMobileAdsPlugin:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
:GoogleMobileAdsPlugin:preReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
:GoogleMobileAdsPlugin:compileReleaseNdk UP-TO-DATE
:GoogleMobileAdsPlugin:compileLint
:GoogleMobileAdsPlugin:copyReleaseLint UP-TO-DATE
:GoogleMobileAdsPlugin:mergeReleaseProguardFiles UP-TO-DATE
:GoogleMobileAdsPlugin:packageReleaseRenderscript UP-TO-DATE
:GoogleMobileAdsPlugin:checkReleaseManifest
:GoogleMobileAdsPlugin:prepareReleaseDependencies
:GoogleMobileAdsPlugin:compileReleaseRenderscript
:GoogleMobileAdsPlugin:generateReleaseResValues UP-TO-DATE
:GoogleMobileAdsPlugin:generateReleaseResources
:GoogleMobileAdsPlugin:packageReleaseResources
:GoogleMobileAdsPlugin:compileReleaseAidl
:GoogleMobileAdsPlugin:generateReleaseBuildConfig
:GoogleMobileAdsPlugin:mergeReleaseShaders
:GoogleMobileAdsPlugin:compileReleaseShaders
:GoogleMobileAdsPlugin:generateReleaseAssets
:GoogleMobileAdsPlugin:mergeReleaseAssets
:GoogleMobileAdsPlugin:processReleaseManifest
:GoogleMobileAdsPlugin:processReleaseResources
:GoogleMobileAdsPlugin:generateReleaseSources
:GoogleMobileAdsPlugin:incrementalReleaseJavaCompilationSafeguard
:GoogleMobileAdsPlugin:compileReleaseJavaWithJavac
:GoogleMobileAdsPlugin:processReleaseJavaRes UP-TO-DATE
:GoogleMobileAdsPlugin:transformResourcesWithMergeJavaResForRelease
:GoogleMobileAdsPlugin:transformClassesAndResourcesWithSyncLibJarsForRelease
:GoogleMobileAdsPlugin:mergeReleaseJniLibFolders
:GoogleMobileAdsPlugin:transformNative_libsWithMergeJniLibsForRelease
:GoogleMobileAdsPlugin:transformNative_libsWithSyncJniLibsForRelease
:GoogleMobileAdsPlugin:bundleRelease
:MainLibProj:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
:MainLibProj:preReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
:MainLibProj:compileReleaseNdk UP-TO-DATE
:MainLibProj:compileLint
:MainLibProj:copyReleaseLint UP-TO-DATE
:MainLibProj:mergeReleaseProguardFiles UP-TO-DATE
:MainLibProj:packageReleaseRenderscript UP-TO-DATE
:MainLibProj:checkReleaseManifest
:MainLibProj:prepareReleaseDependencies
:MainLibProj:compileReleaseRenderscript
:MainLibProj:generateReleaseResValues UP-TO-DATE
:MainLibProj:generateReleaseResources
:MainLibProj:packageReleaseResources
:MainLibProj:compileReleaseAidl
:MainLibProj:generateReleaseBuildConfig
:MainLibProj:mergeReleaseShaders
:MainLibProj:compileReleaseShaders
:MainLibProj:generateReleaseAssets
:MainLibProj:mergeReleaseAssets
:MainLibProj:processReleaseManifest
:MainLibProj:processReleaseResources
:MainLibProj:generateReleaseSources
:MainLibProj:incrementalReleaseJavaCompilationSafeguard
:MainLibProj:compileReleaseJavaWithJavac
:MainLibProj:processReleaseJavaRes UP-TO-DATE
:MainLibProj:transformResourcesWithMergeJavaResForRelease
:MainLibProj:transformClassesAndResourcesWithSyncLibJarsForRelease
:MainLibProj:mergeReleaseJniLibFolders
:MainLibProj:transformNative_libsWithMergeJniLibsForRelease
:MainLibProj:transformNative_libsWithSyncJniLibsForRelease
:MainLibProj:bundleRelease
:prepareAnimatedVectorDrawable2531Library UP-TO-DATE
:prepareAppcompatV72531Library UP-TO-DATE
:prepareCardviewV72531Library UP-TO-DATE
:prepareComAndroidSupportMultidex101Library UP-TO-DATE
:prepareCustomtabs2531Library UP-TO-DATE
:prepareFacebookAndroidSdk4230Library UP-TO-DATE
:prepareFacebookAndroidWrapper7100Library UP-TO-DATE
:prepareGradleOutGoogleMobileAdsPluginUnspecifiedLibrary
:prepareGradleOutMainLibProjUnspecifiedLibrary
:preparePlayServicesAds1021Library UP-TO-DATE
:preparePlayServicesAdsLite1021Library UP-TO-DATE
:preparePlayServicesAuth1021Library UP-TO-DATE
:preparePlayServicesAuthBase1021Library UP-TO-DATE
:preparePlayServicesBase1021Library UP-TO-DATE
:preparePlayServicesBasement1021Library UP-TO-DATE
:preparePlayServicesGames1021Library UP-TO-DATE
:preparePlayServicesGass1021Library UP-TO-DATE
:preparePlayServicesNearby1021Library UP-TO-DATE
:preparePlayServicesTasks1021Library UP-TO-DATE
:prepareSupportCompat2531Library UP-TO-DATE
:prepareSupportCoreUi2531Library UP-TO-DATE
:prepareSupportCoreUtils2531Library UP-TO-DATE
:prepareSupportFragment2531Library UP-TO-DATE
:prepareSupportMediaCompat2531Library UP-TO-DATE
:prepareSupportV42531Library UP-TO-DATE
:prepareSupportVectorDrawable2531Library UP-TO-DATE
:prepareDebugDependencies
:compileDebugAidl UP-TO-DATE
:compileDebugRenderscript UP-TO-DATE
:generateDebugBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE
:mergeDebugShaders UP-TO-DATE
:compileDebugShaders UP-TO-DATE
:generateDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
:mergeDebugAssets
:generateDebugResValues UP-TO-DATE
:generateDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:mergeDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:processDebugManifest UP-TO-DATE
:processDebugResources
:generateDebugSources
:incrementalDebugJavaCompilationSafeguard UP-TO-DATE
:compileDebugJavaWithJavac
:compileDebugNdk UP-TO-DATE
:compileDebugSources
:prePackageMarkerForDebug
:transformClassesWithJarMergingForDebug FAILED

BUILD FAILED

Total time: 20.534 secs
]
exit code: 1
UnityEditor.Android.Command.Run (System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo psi, UnityEditor.Android.WaitingForProcessToExit waitingForProcessToExit, System.String errorMsg)
UnityEditor.Android.GradleWrapper.RunJava (System.String args, System.String workingdir, UnityEditor.Android.Progress progress)
UnityEditor.Android.GradleWrapper.Run (System.String workingdir, System.String task, UnityEditor.Android.Progress progress)
UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.Tasks.BuildGradleProject.Execute (UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.PostProcessorContext context)
UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.PostProcessRunner.RunAllTasks (UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.PostProcessorContext context)
UnityEditor.HostView:OnGUI()
```

I have searched everywhere but it just says delete the duplicate file. What file should I delete? Is there any other solution?

Comment: please post your gradle config

Comment: Hi, I'm sorry I haven't noticed your reply earlier, but I just ended up giving up on gradle and configuring my project to use google mobile ads lite library instead of the normal one. That takes care of the dex overflow problem, which just means I don't have to use gradle